# counting array indexes

Tags: arrays, algorithm, indexing, language-agnostic, counting

If I have an array of numbers like [5, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2]

I want to count the number of times I can continuously index the array until we come to an index we already visited, like this:

```
A[0] = 5 
A[5] = 2
A[2] = 3
A[3] = 2 stop here because we already indexed 2.
```

So my problem is: without using additional data structure to store the previously visited indices, is there a way I can tell my program when to stop indexing?

Comment: I am personally finding this question to be unclear.  What programming language is this to be solved with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are treating this array as a directed graph. If that is so, then what you're really asking for is how to detect cycles in a directed graph.

See:

- [Best algorithm for detecting cycles in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)
- [Find all paths with cycles in directed graph, given the source vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885647/find-all-paths-with-cycles-in-directed-graph-given-the-source-vertex)
- [How to detect if a directed graph is cyclic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525282/how-to-detect-if-a-directed-graph-is-cyclic)

To answer your question specifically though: If you were wandering around in a labyrinth, how do you tell if you've been to a particular junction before? You might consider dropping breadcrumbs or unspooling a thread to remind you where you have been. It's the same thing here. You'll need to either annotate your original array with a "visited" flag, or keep a copy of the indexes you've visited in your own array.

Answer (score 0):

If you start out with your array elements initialized to an invalid value, say -1, then you can stop if an array element has already been assigned, as in the following pseudocode:

```
if (A[x] == -1)
    A[x] = y
else
    stop
```